# Tennis game algorithm and maths

Tags: algorithm, intersection, mathematics

Tennis courts are real dimensions and game is 3D

Ball has position (x,y,z), speed(vx,vy,vz) and acceleration (ax,ay,az)

Game has 30 fps and on each update (1/30sec) it has these properties

```
vx +=ax;
vy +=ay;
vz +=az;

ball.x += vx;
ball.y += vy;
ball.z += vz;

function hitBall(destinationx, destinationy=0, destinationz) {
    // calculate vx, vy, vz, so ball imapcts  the point (destinationX, 0, destinationZ)
    // destinationY = 0 = bounce on floor 
    vx = ....
    vy = ....
    vz = ....
// I guess this problem has infinite solution, so we must intersect with 1 point
// intersection line is (x,1,12)
// 12 is middle of the tennis court and 1 is 1 metter above the ground.
// ball passes there 1 meter above the ground.

}
```

Any clue on how to resolve that math problem ?

regards

[image]

Google doc : 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1EiUYpalDXlJUgjg8aIxLiWENgZJW7fnH4bGHsj1jb9I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to the Site! The description is vague (IMO). And I feel there is an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem here, in other words you are asking how to resolve collision, but it's not clear if you already know the hit point? which I don't understand. What destination is? is it the hit point? What do you mean by "// I guess this problem has infinite solution, so we must intersect with 1 point
// intersection point is (5,1,12)" Why do you suppose that ?

Comment: hitBall is when player hist the ball. Destination of the ball is (destinbationX, destinationY=, destinationZ) and this trajactory should pass through the intersection point (when the net is) and pass 1 metter above it.

Comment: and you are right: we cannot know the X of the intersaction point: I corrected that !

Answer (score 2):

So what I understand from you description is that you have a destination point and you want to shoot a projectile so it hits that point, in other words to reach specific coordinates.

Now this can be done using [basic projectile equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile).

The following equation gives the initial angle that is needed to hit specific coordinate.

[image]

Where:

- g: the gravitational acceleration—usually taken to be 9.81 m/s2 near the Earth's   surface
- θ: the angle at which the projectile is launched
- v: the velocity at which the projectile is launched
- y0: the initial height of the projectile
- d: the total horizontal distance traveled by the projectile

Now the problem is that the distance depends on the initial velocity vector (direction, and speed). So in order to calculate this using the above equation you need to fix one of them. So you assume you are shooting at fixed angle (e.g.45 degree), and then calculate the speed of the vector or vice versa.

[image]

Comment: I added a fixed point: the one which is 1 metter above the ground with y=10 ! (when the ball passes through the net).

I do not need to caluclate the angle, but vx,vy and vz instead.